# Rsync --bwlimit not working when use -z

Tags: linux

I use rsync to transfer large data from host to another. The source path and destination path are mounted with nfs.

I want to use --bwlimit to limit the bandwidth, but I found that when the parameter -z is used, --bwlimit seems to not work.

like this:

```bsh
$ rsync --progress -lptgoD -z -HXSR --bwlimit=1024 --numeric-ids -r /source_dir/ /dest_dir/

sending incremental file list
./
xxx/
xxx/file1
    2,943,688,704 100% 7.87MB/s 0:05:56(xfr#1, to-chk=1/4)
xxx/file2
    2.939,400,192 100% 7.85MB/s 0:05:56(xfr#2, to-chk=0/4)
sent 720,566,933bytes received 65bytes 1,011,322,10 bytes/sec
total size is 5,883,088,896 speedup is 8.16
```

during tansfer data,  use `iotop` and `nfsiostat-systat -mth 2` tools to monitor network bandwidth, all arrounds 5MB/s~10MB/s. So what wrong here ?

rsync version 3.1.2, forgive my poor english, thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it actually work without `-z`?! In neither case is `rsync` doing a network transfer (it does not know or care that the filesystem is network mounted, it will treat both source and destination as "local").

Comment: Are your files text files? Test again with a file that compresses badly.

Answer (score 0):

The `--bwlimit` and `-z` (`--compress`) options are ignored unless you are performing a network transfer.

In your case, as far as `rsync` is concerned you are doing a local transfer - even if the source or destination is a mounted network drive it's still seen as part of the local filesystem and therefore considered to be local.

Another side-effect of local to local transfers is that `rsync` either transfers or skips entire files; there is no consideration for sending only changed blocks as with network copies. Effectively, it's reduced to not much more than just `cp`

Comment: The `--bwlimit` seems to work fine here, local copy. The transfer rates are higher with `-z`, but depends on the compressibility. Related: [bwlimit on rsync locally](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2008-March/020540.html)

Comment: @Freddy what version of rsync are you using, please?

Comment: 3.1.3 (Debian buster), 3.1.2 (Ubuntu 18.04)